# Dark/light Theme Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

i have tied so many ways for switching Between Dark and Light Mode in Blazor.with different packages and Even Manually with css.
but they never workedout For Me.can someone Give me complete guid on how can i do this?Thank

here is the latest thing i have tried with MudBlazor:

```
<MudThemeProvider Theme="new MudTheme()" @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode"/>
<MudIconButton @onclick="ToggleDark" Icon="@modeIcon"/>

@code {
bool _isDarkMode = false;
private string modeIcon => _isDarkMode? Icons.Filled.DarkMode : Icons.Filled.LightMode;
private void ToggleDark() => _isDarkMode = !_isDarkMode;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MudBlazor, but the documentation says the IconButton has an `OnClick` parameter - perhaps you should use that instead of `@onclick`?

Answer (score 6):

so basically, this might be late, but i will post it for if someone was looking for it
mudblazor docs been updated

[link can be found here](https://mudblazor.com/customization/overview#theme-provider)

```
<MudThemeProvider @ref="@_mudThemeProvider" @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode"/>

@code {
    private bool _isDarkMode;
    private MudThemeProvider _mudThemeProvider;
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _isDarkMode = await _mudThemeProvider.GetSystemPreference();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

basically this worked for auto theme, which is fine by me for now

Answer (score 4):

### Here's an example:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QammkMHEJKzZundd

```
<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@isDarkMode"/>
<MudSwitch
    @bind-Checked="@isDarkMode"
    Color="Color.Primary"
    Label="Toggle Light/Dark Mode"/>

@code{
    private bool isDarkMode;
}
```

### Source:

This example is a simplified version of an example from the official MudBlazor documentation. Here's a link:
https://mudblazor.com/customization/overview#dark-palette

Comment: I already tried it. It doesn't work

Comment: In that case, you may need to provide more info since this is a code example from the official MudBlazor documentation. Feel free to have a look at the installation guide of MudBlazor just in case: https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#manual-install-add-components

Comment: Theme="_theme" - remove this and will work just fine on default theme.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this as well. The MudBlazor docs neglect to inform you that you must call `StateHasChanged()` from the layout component (MainLayout) after toggling `IsDarkMode`. I discovered this after researching how their documentation website works. Look at (https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/d05b8d0ef3480c69a7db754d0d8ce9abdbd544ad/src/MudBlazor.Docs/Shared/MainLayout.razor.cs)

The operative code is (edited):

```
public partial class MainLayout : LayoutComponentBase, IDisposable
{ 
   [Inject] private  LayoutService LayoutService { get; set; }
   
   private MudThemeProvider _mudThemeProvider;

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       LayoutService.MajorUpdateOccured += LayoutServiceOnMajorUpdateOccured;
       base.OnInitialized();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       LayoutService.MajorUpdateOccured -= LayoutServiceOnMajorUpdateOccured;
   }

   private void LayoutServiceOnMajorUpdateOccured(object sender, EventArgs e) => StateHasChanged();
}
```

Note that MainLayout subscribes to the `MajorUpdateOccured` event and calls `StateHasChanged` when the event is invoked.

If you look at `LayoutService` (https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/d05b8d0ef3480c69a7db754d0d8ce9abdbd544ad/src/MudBlazor.Docs/Services/LayoutService.cs), you will see how `ToggleDarkMode` works

```
public event EventHandler MajorUpdateOccured;

private void OnMajorUpdateOccured() => MajorUpdateOccured?.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);

public async Task ToggleDarkMode()
{
   IsDarkMode = !IsDarkMode;
   _userPreferences.DarkTheme = IsDarkMode;
   await _userPreferencesService.SaveUserPreferences(_userPreferences);
   OnMajorUpdateOccured();
}
```

In summary, you have to call `StateHasChanged` from the layout so that the entire site is re-rendered. So you have to provide a way to propagate the dark mode change from your settings screen to your layout component.

Comment: its funny they are not using blazor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have implemented it this way.

Inside my `MainLayout.razor` file I have added an `onclick` event at my `MudIconButton`:

`<MudIconButton @onclick="ToggleDarkMode" Color="Color.Inherit" Icon="@modeIcon" />`

You can see it in line 12 below.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_isDarkMode" Theme="_theme"/>
<MudDialogProvider />
<MudSnackbarProvider />

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="1" Color="Color.Surface">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="ml-3">Application Name Here</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton @onclick="ToggleDarkMode" Color="Color.Inherit" Icon="@modeIcon" />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.End" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Always" Elevation="2">
        <NavMenu />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large" Class="my-16 pt-16">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

I have then extracted the code from the razor file to a code behind-file for `MainLayout.razor`. See below:

```
using MudBlazor;

namespace ApplicationName.Shared
{
    public partial class MainLayout
    {
        private MudTheme _theme = new();
        private string modeIcon => _isDarkMode ? Icons.Outlined.DarkMode : @Icons.Outlined.LightMode;
        private bool _isDarkMode;
        bool _drawerOpen = true;
        void ToggleDarkMode()
        {
            _isDarkMode = !_isDarkMode;
        }

        void DrawerToggle()
        {
            _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
        }

    }
}
```

Here I am changing the icon depending on the dark mode setting from the client and then updating the bool in the method `ToggleDarkMode()`. Remember to update the namespace.

At runtime, this is what happens:
[Live demo of MudBlazor Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kfbS.gif)

Hope this works for you and everyone else who has the same problem :)

Answer (score -4):

you should give a condition in class.
so in your claas:

```
<div class="light ? class : class2"></div>


export defaut{
data(){
return {
light : true;
}
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to Blazor - the question is about using the MudBlazor components in a Blazor project.